# Create a function out of this php code

Tags: php

I just need some help creating a php function out of this code or in other words just to wrap this code in a php function :

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])){

    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

    if(ctype_alnum($username)){

        $check = mysql_query("SELECT username,first_name FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($check)===1){

            $get = mysql_fetch_assoc($check);
            $username = $get['username'];
            $firstname = $get['first_name'];

            echo '<div id="mini_profile">This is '.$username.'\'s profile.</div>';

            }else{

            header("Location: index.php");
            exit();


            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: May not help with the question but I would recommend that you stop using `mysql_` functions as they are being [deprecated](http://www.deprecatedphp.com). Look into `mysqli_` or `PDO`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really easy :)

```
function yourFunc() {
if (isset($_GET['id'])){

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

if(ctype_alnum($username)){

    $check = mysql_query("SELECT username,first_name FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($check)===1){

        $get = mysql_fetch_assoc($check);
        $username = $get['username'];
        $firstname = $get['first_name'];

        echo '<div id="mini_profile">This is '.$username.'\'s profile.</div>';

        }else{

        header("Location: index.php");
        exit();


        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: wow i tried this before didnt work because i didnt go by this order function code() {} but i just went function code() { forgot the } at the end thanks again ... i feel dumb now haha

Comment: You might want to pass parameters to the function instead: `function login($username) { ... }` and pass the `$_GET['id']`. Like that you can also login from a $_POST, or something else. Also you might want to add `AND password='$password'`. As it is you are very vulnerable: Someone can enter an url giving any id to the querystring and logon as that person!

Comment: this is not a login script ... its just to get the username as and id for the www.website.com/members.php?id=$username its just for the part ?id=$username

Comment: Ah yes I see now :) Also check njk's comment: [`mysql_query`](http://www.php.net/mysql_query) is deprecated. From php.net: _Suggested alternatives

Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include: mysqli_query() PDO::query()_

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend for all your answers

Answer (score 2):

```
function getMyDivElement($name) {
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($name);

    if(ctype_alnum($username)) {
        $check = mysql_query("SELECT username,first_name FROM users WHERE username='{$username}'");
        if(is_resource($check) && ($get = mysql_fetch_assoc($check))) {
            $username = $get['username'];
            $firstname = $get['first_name']; //You need this?

            return '<div id="mini_profile">This is '.$username.'\'s profile.</div>';
        }
    }

    return null;
}

//usage
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $div = getMyDivElement($_GET['id']);
    if($div) {
        echo $div;
    } else {
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is to return the echo statement as a string.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of creating a function is to provide reuseable code. This means you are encapsulating the logic, allowing you to change the inner workings of the code without it affecting the actual usage of the function and to avoid tedious repetition.

In your example you should think about the areas that fall into this category. I personally can see that several functions that could be made here.

Example, not run but should give you ideas.

```
<?php

  function getUser($username)
  {
    if (is_string($username) && strlen($username)) {
      $query  = "
        SELECT 
          username, firstname 
        FROM 
          users 
        WHERE 
          username = :username
      ";  
      $result = executeQuery($query, array("username" => $username));
      return $result->fetch();
    }
  }

  function getDatabase($host, $db, $user, $password)
  { 
    return new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname, $user, $pass");
  }

  function executeQuery($sql, array $params = array())
  {
    $db   = getDatabase();
    $conn = $db->prepare($sql);

    return $conn->execute($params);
  }

  function validateInput($input)
  {
    return ctype_alnum($input);
  }

  function advanceTo($page, $params) 
  {
    header("Location: $page.php");
    exit();
  }


if (isset($_GET["username"])){
  if (validateInput($_GET["username"])) {
    $user = getUser($_GET["username"]);
    if (! empty($user)) {
      // authUserAndSetSessionForUser($user);
      /** This page is then directed to and welcome message shown **/
      advanceTo("user-home-page", array($user));
    } else {
      advanceTo("index");
    }
  }
}

?>
```